# Why do I fail to use python in Mathematica?

Tags: external-language-cell

I have installed the required python package `zmq` as shown below. But when I tried it in Mathematica, it failed.

[image][image]

I am currently using Mathematica 13 as well as python 3.11. Are the two software unable to work together because of their version?

Comment: First, try restarting Mathematica. If this does not help, there is an instruction to manually register your python at the bottom of [Configure Python for ExternalEvaluate](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/ConfigurePythonForExternalEvaluate.html). Evaluate `where python` inside your command prompt, then use this path in `RegisterExternalEvaluator`.

Comment: @Domen I think I know the problem. My `python` is inside a folder protected by Windows(because it was downloaded from *Microsoft Store*), I shall install it another way.